# Java graphics - repaint an image without removing another

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, repaint

I am using Graphics g to draw an image for my player and a map. Whenever the player moves I want to update the player image to the new location without updating the map image. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Sorry about my messy code.

```
   Main:
package Main;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static JFrame frame;

    static int size = 32;
    static int width = size*20;
    static int height = size*17;

    static playerObj p = new playerObj(200,200);

    static tileMap grid = new tileMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width-9, height-9));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(new drawGraphics());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

drawGraphics:
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class drawGraphics extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    boolean running = true;
    boolean renderMap = true;

    playerObj p = Main.p;
    int size = Main.size;
    static int x = 0;
    static int y = 0;

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);

    public drawGraphics() {
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new controls());
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        thread.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (renderMap) {
            map(d);
        }

        player(g);

        repaint();
    }

    public void player(Graphics g) {
        try {
            BufferedImage pImg = ImageIO.read(new File("images/player.png"));
            g.drawImage(pImg, p.getX(), p.getY(), null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void map(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("2dfsdf");
        Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 0; i < tileMap.map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tileMap.map[i].length; j++) {
                d.setColor(tileMap.map[i][j].getC());
                d.fillRect(tileMap.map[i][j].getX(), tileMap.map[i][j].getY(),
                        Main.size, Main.size);
                if (tileMap.map[i][j].solid()) {
                    d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    d.drawRect(tileMap.map[i][j].getX(),
                            tileMap.map[i][j].getY(), Main.size, Main.size);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        if (controls.up) {
            controls.goUp();
            y--;
            repaint();
        }
        if (controls.down) {
            controls.goDown();
            y++;
            repaint();
        }
        if (controls.left) {
            controls.goLeft();
            x--;
            repaint();
        }
        if (controls.right) {
            controls.goRight();
            x++;
            repaint();
        }
        if (controls.place) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running == true) {
            move();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Graphics where?

Comment: On a JFrame. Would it be better if I just copied and pasted some of my code into the post?

Comment: Yes, but don't just dump a bunch of unnecessary code. We need to see how you're drawing things. And what do you mean by update the map - do you mean draw it?

Comment: I've added some of my code into my question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't draw directly in a JFrame but rather in a JPanel that is displayed within the JFrame.

If you're using Swing as your GUI library, then draw the background as a BufferedImage, and draw that first in your paintComponent method. Then draw your image sprite at whatever location needed next:

```
@Override  // this is in a JPanel extended class
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   if (backgroundImg != null) {
      g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
   }
   if (spriteImg != null) {
      g.drawImage(spriteImg, spriteX, spriteY, null);
   }
}
```

Some issues with your code:

- Don't override `paint` and then call `super.paintComponent` inside of it.
- Instead override `paintComponent` and call the same super method inside.
- Never call `repaint()` inside of paint or paintComponent. Use a Swing Timer instead.
- In your `player(...)` method, you re-read the image in each time the method is called, something that will slow your painting down to a crawl. Don't do this, but instead read the image in once, and save it to a variable.

Comment: How can I use a Swing Timer to repaint()? Previously I was using repaint() within my move() method which is run every 10 milliseconds if the player moved, would that be ok?

Comment: @TIMMEHf32432: In your `player(...)` method, you re-read the image in each time the method is called, something that will slow your painting down to a crawl. Don't do this, but instead read the image in once, and save it to a variable. Also check out the [Timer tutorial](In your `player(...)` method, you re-read the image in each time the method is called, something that will slow your painting down to a crawl. Don't do this, but instead read the image in once, and save it to a variable.).

Comment: Alright I've saved the player image to a variable so it will only ready it if it is equal to null. I'll check out the Timer tutorial now but is there any way to stop the rectangles I'm using to create my map in map() from needing to be repainted every time? I want to turn these rectangles into images later on and I know it will make my game really slow if I need to repaint the map every time the player moves.

Comment: Ahhhh saving the image data to a variable instead of reading it every time stops it from slowing it down. Thank you very much!